# a post version of window.href for javascript. does it exist?

Tags: javascript, html, post, get

Currently I have a section of my website where there is a usable toolbar made from a set of images from a sprite sheet. Different functions happen when each item is clicked. One function is saving changes and updating the entire page.

Currently I'm using the onclick functionality and the get method to fetch the page again but google is catching on but I don't want search engines scanning the page, so I need a post method instead.

Here's a sample of the method I use to make a GET request:

```
<!-- other parts of the page -->
<div ID="someimagefromsheet" onclick="updatepage();">
</div>
<!-- other parts of the page -->

<script>
function updatepage(){
    window.location.href="http://example.com/index.php?datatosave="+somedata;
}
</script>
```

I feel I need to replace window.location.href with some other set of functions.

Is there a way I can turn this request from using the GET method to using the POST method without resorting to AJAX functionality?

Comment: Many frameworks for this kind of work have been written. Don't roll your own, use your time to learn one of them instead.

Answer (score 0):

No. Setting `window.href` invariably results in a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a form and post it:

```
function updatepage(){
  var f = document.createElement('form');
  f.method = "POST";
  f.action = "http://example.com/index.php";
  var i = document.createElement("input");
  i.type = "hidden";
  i.name = "datatosave";
  i.value = somedata;
  f.appendChild(i);
  f.submit();
}
```